# PHP simplexml retrieve first n records in xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i've just started using simplexml and i have the following statement that displays all the records in the xml:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $rec) { 
    echo $rec->dist . "<br />";
}
```

For pagination purposes, how would I go about retrieving a range of records from the xml, e.g. just the first 10 records (0-9)?

thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
$children = $xml->children() ;
$num = count($children) ;
$start = 10 ; // zero-based index
$end = 20 ; // zero-based index
for ($i = $start; $i < $end ; $i++) {
    echo $children[$i]->dist . "<br />";
}
```

Previous version :

```
$line = 1 ;
foreach($xml->children() as $rec) { 
    echo $rec->dist . "<br />";
    if ($line++ == 10) break;
}
```

This will show 10 first elements.

Comment: Syscall, that works great for the first 10, but how would i go about specifying a range after that? e.g. elements 10-20, etc.

Comment: this seems to work, but not sure if it's inelegant:
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->children() as $rec) { 
    if ($line++ >10) {
  echo $perf->dist . "<br />";
 }
    if ($line++ == 30) break;
}

Comment: @oewebby I've updated my anwser for a more elegant version.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use XPath to just extract the nodes...

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$start = 2;
$end = 7;
$data = $xml->xpath("/*/*[position()>= $start and not(position() > $end)]");
print_r( $data);
```

This returns an array of the elements your after, which you can then process as needed.